# Openni_tracker no skeleton data published in /tf

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, openi-tracker, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I want to visualize the skeleton transforms in rviz. After starting openni.launch, openni_tracker and doing the psi-pose, i expect the different body-part frames in the tf-topic....but the only frame i receive is called /user, which tracks my position. Am I doing something wrong with the calibration or why are these body-part-frames missing? Or maybe is there something wrong with my tf-Configuration?

Here are the informations i get after "rostopic echo /tf":

---

### transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1346418001
    nsecs: 185126405
  frame_id: /openni_camera
child_frame_id: /openni_rgb_frame
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: -0.04
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

---

### transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1346418001
    nsecs: 63344952
  frame_id: /camera_depth_optical_frame
child_frame_id: /user
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -0.260202636719
    y: 0.157726348877
    z: 0.974624938965
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

---

### transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1346418001
    nsecs: 285380278
  frame_id: /openni_camera
child_frame_id: /openni_rgb_frame
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: -0.04
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

---

### transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1346418001
    nsecs: 247788965
  frame_id: /openni_camera
child_frame_id: /openni_depth_frame
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: -0.02
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

---

I use ROS electric and Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric.

Best Regards
Flezzo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42566/openni_tracker-no-skeleton-data-published-in-/tf/) by [Flezzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3105/flezzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flezzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3105/flezzo/) on 2012-08-30**:
There is just the /user transform and some irrelevant transforms (i think they are not relevant for my problem) posted on the /tf topic.There appear no head-transform for example, after echoing the /tf topic.After using roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch, only the /user transform is published

**Comment by [Flezzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3105/flezzo/) on 2012-09-03**:
I solved my problem by using the pi_tracker instead of the openni_tracker....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check if there are any transforms posted on the /tf topic? RVIZ will only display the transforms if you provied a full tree to the fixed frame... You can also set your fixed frame to your /camera_link-frame to check if the tracker works...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2